# android-MNC project won’t run on devices prior to API level 'android-MNC'

Tags: android, android-studio, android-6.0-marshmallow

Shortly after the Google I/O keynote and the consecutive talks about Android M features, I started playing around with the new SDK functions, e.g., runtime permissions. For that [it is necessary to set](https://developer.android.com/preview/features/runtime-permissions.html#coding) the `compileSdkVersion` as well as the `targetSdkVersion` to `android-mnc`.
When running the project on a Nexus 5 with the Android M Developer Preview installed, Android Studio installs the application and it works fine on the device.

If I set the `minSdkVersion` to, e.g., 10 to test it on a 2.3.6 device or to 21 to test it on a 5.0 device, it still works on the M-Nexus5 but not on the aforementioned devices with lower-than-M API versions.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"
    compileSdkVersion 'android-MNC'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "de.FOOBAR.permtestproject"
        minSdkVersion 10
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 23
        versionName "1.0"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
}
```

As you can see in the following screenshot, my level-21 device is shown as incompatible even though I set the minSdkVersion to 10 and not to the claimed level of 22.

[image: Available devices dialogue in the foreground, gradle build file in the background]

Lowering the `targetSdkVersion` to `21` doesn’t make a difference. Changing the `compileSdkVersion` is not an option as the permission request calls have not been available in pre-M(NC) SDKs.

Trying to run the application on a pre-M device always fails with the error `INSTALL_FAILED_OLDER_SDK`.

[image: INSTALL_FAILED_OLDER_SDK]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android Studio : Failure \[INSTALL\_FAILED\_OLDER\_SDK\]](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24465289/android-studio-failure-install-failed-older-sdk)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Quoting myself](https://commonsware.com/blog/2015/06/05/supporting-m-developer-preview-previous-versions.html):

> In the case of the M Developer Preview, the `compileSdkVersion` value of `android-MNC` causes the build process to put MNC in as the `minSdkVersion` and `targetSdkVersion` in the generated manifest.
>
> Fortunately, manifests are text files.
>
> So, here is an android closure that can build an app module that compiles against MNC but will run on API Level 15+ devices:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 'android-MNC'
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.0 rc1"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 15
    }

    // based on http://stackoverflow.com/a/27372806/115145

    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            output.processManifest.doLast {
                def manifestOutFile = output.processManifest.manifestOutputFile
                def newFileContents = manifestOutFile.getText('UTF-8').replace("MNC", "15")
                manifestOutFile.write(newFileContents, 'UTF-8')
            }
        }
    }
}
```

> This takes a very “caveman” approach to the problem, reading in the generated manifest, replacing all occurrences of `MNC` with `15`, and writing the adjusted manifest back out. This will fail on projects that have `MNC` somewhere else, like an activity’s class name. It also sets both `minSdkVersion` and `targetSdkVersion` to the same value. A more sophisticated script would replace those individual attributes — the proof of this is left as an exercise for the reader. Similarly, a more powerful script would read the desired values out of `defaultConfig` and apply them. And, a safety-conscious edition of this would only apply this for debuggable variants, thereby helping to reduce the impact of a drooling idiot trying to ship a release build that performs this override. This is merely a proof of concept, not implementing all possible bells and whistles.
>
> Again, doing this and releasing the results to the Play Store or elsewhere is monumentally idiotic. Use this for testing only.

Comment: At first it seemed like it didn’t work but cleaning the project helped. I got it working both on the level 10 device as well as on the level 21 device. Thank you very much!