# Android Studio isn't recognizing the checkSelfPermission

Tags: android, permissions, android-6.0-marshmallow

Is it possible to run [Google Sample - RuntimePermissionsBasic](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-RuntimePermissionsBasic)

On devices with OS less than MNC (Android M)?

This project comes with:

```
compileSdkVersion "android-MNC"
targetSdkVersion "MNC"
```

So far so good, running it on less than M OS will get:

`INSTALL_FAILED_OLDER_SDK`

But when I changed it to:

```
compileSdkVersion 22
targetSdkVersion "MNC"
```

The Android Studio isn't recognizing the `checkSelfPermission (...)` method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So far so good, running it on less than M OS will get: `INSTALL_FAILED_OLDER_SDK`

That is because setting `compileSdkVersion` to `android-MNC` forces the `minSdkVersion` to `MNC` by default. There are [recipes for changing that behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30734545/android-mnc-project-won-t-run-on-devices-prior-to-api-level-android-mnc/30734751#30734751).

> But when I changed it to... The Android Studio isn't recognizing the checkSelfPermission (...) method

`checkSelfPermission()` was introduced in the M Developer Preview and does not exist on older versions of Android.

Comment: @David: The code appears to be set up to support older devices (see the implementation and use of `isMNC()` in `MainActivity`), but the build process does not support it by default. As noted in my answer, there are workarounds to get the app to be able to run on older devices.

Comment: Yes... the isMNC() was the confusing part for me. 10x, I will check the workarounds.

Comment: The only issue with that workaround is that the app will always think that the permission has been granted. Even on M devices.

Comment: @David: The build process workaround that I linked to is simply for testing purposes. AFAIK, this sample app is demonstrating how to request permissions, not the best practices for when and why to request permissions.

Answer (score 5):

Try to add [`ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/ContextCompat.html#checkSelfPermission(android.content.Context,%20java.lang.String)) instead just checkSelfPermission...for me it works...