# Java 8 in Android N Preview

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-7.0-nougat, android-n-preview

The official Java 8 [announcement for Android N Preview](http://android-developers.blogspot.de/2016/03/first-preview-of-android-n-developer.html) says the following:

> With Android’s Jack compiler, you can now use many popular Java 8
>   language features, including lambdas and more, on Android versions as
>   far back as **Gingerbread**. (…) Some Java 8 language features — like
>   default and static methods, streams, and functional interfaces — are
>   also now available on N and above.

I'm using the following gradle configuration with `minSdkVersion 15` to try some Java 8 in a small project:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 'android-N'
    buildToolsVersion '24.0.0 rc1'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "org.sergiiz.thermometer"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 'N'
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        jackOptions{
            enabled true
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        targetCompatibility 1.8
        sourceCompatibility 1.8
    }
   //...
}
```

But the Deployment Target selector shows `minSdk(API23, N preview)`. Is it expected behaviour?

[image]

Is there a list of Java 8 features/packages available as far back as Gingerbread and do you know which gradle settings or support libs are needed to use Java 8 features on API<23?

Comment: I can't help you with the Gradle settings (haven't tried myself yet). But the list of supported Java 8 features in pre-Android N is easy: It's lambda expressions / method references only - nothing else to my knowledge.

Comment: Possible duplicate of this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35929484/android-n-cannot-run-on-lower-api-though-minsdk-set-to-14

Answer (score 2):

> But the Deployment Target selector shows minSdk(API23, N preview). Is it expected behaviour?

Yes. The N Developer Preview is set up to only run on N devices. Your `targetSdkVersion 'N'` line is implicitly changing your `minSdkVersion` to also be `N`.

> do you know which gradle settings or support libs are needed to use Java 8 features on API<23?

I recommend that you not worry about the Java 8 features on older devices until Android N exits "developer preview" mode or the Android tools team provides specific non-N instructions.