# Cannot run programm on real device

Tags: android

Why this error is occurring?

See this [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B4w3S.jpg)
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Studio - Unable to run app on device minSdk(API 23, N) != device Sdk(API 22)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36546036/android-studio-unable-to-run-app-on-device-minsdkapi-23-n-device-sdkapi)

Comment: its duplicate question. Answer is given in this question

Comment: you have to use search before asking, and the questions that already answered are not welcome to re-ask.

Answer (score 0):

In your build.gradle file you have to change

> minSdkVersion 26

to

> minSdkVersion 27

Your project has two build.gradle files, you make the change in app/build.gradle