# Run android app on API 16 Handy from from Android Studio 2.0

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm not that experienced in android development unfortunately. I downloaded Android Studio for my Mac, installed java and did everything that was described in official documentation from developers.android.com (http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/index.html, http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/running-app.html).

Then I tried to create a first basic project and run it on my Samsung Galaxy S2 handy. Unfortunately I was not able to run it, because Android Studio complained that my Galaxy S2 supports API 16, while the project requires API 23 (`midSdk(API 23, N, preview) != deviceSdk(API 16)`).

It is not obvious for me why does this error exist, because I selected minimum supported version API 16 when I created a project, I have to google for a solution and look on different topics on stackoverflow.

My build.gradle file content was:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 'android-N'
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.daniel.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 'N'
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.+'
}
```

I had to change it to:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 16
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.daniel.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 16
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.+'
}
```

After that I was able to select my Samsung Galaxy S2 and click "Run", however it did not solve the problem completely, I still cannot run my application because now I get some compilation errors from Grandle:

```
/Users/daniel/AndroidStudioProjects/MyApplication3/app/build/intermediates/res/merged/debug/values-ldltr-v21/values-ldltr-v21.xml
Error:(3) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Spinner.Underlined'.
/Users/daniel/AndroidStudioProjects/MyApplication3/app/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.android.support/appcompat-v7/24.0.0-alpha2/res/values-v17/values-v17.xml
Error:(3, 5) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:textAlignment'.
Error:(6, 5) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:paddingEnd'.
Error:(10, 5) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:layout_marginEnd'.
Error:(13, 5) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:paddingEnd'.
Error:(16, 5) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:layout_marginStart'.
Error:(19, 5) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:layout_alignParentStart'.
Error:(19, 5) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:textAlignment'.
Error:(23, 5) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:paddingEnd'.
Error:(23, 5) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:paddingStart'.
Error:(27, 5) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:layout_alignParentStart'.
Error:(30, 5) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:layout_toStartOf'.
Error:(33, 5) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:layout_alignParentEnd'.
Error:(36, 5) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:layout_toEndOf'.
Error:(36, 5) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:layout_toStartOf'.
Error:(40, 5) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:layout_marginStart'.
Error:(43, 5) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:paddingEnd'.
Error:(43, 5) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:paddingStart'.
Error:(47, 5) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:paddingEnd'.
Error:(47, 5) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:paddingStart'.
/Users/daniel/AndroidStudioProjects/MyApplication3/app/build/intermediates/res/merged/debug/values-v21/values-v21.xml
Error:(13) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Inverse'.
Error:(15) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Large.Inverse'.
Error:(21) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Medium.Inverse'.
Error:(28) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Small.Inverse'.
Error:(212) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ProgressBar'.
Error:(214) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ProgressBar.Horizontal'.
Error:(222) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Theme.Material'.
Error:(232) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Theme.Material.Light'.
Error:(172) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.AutoCompleteTextView'.
Error:(185) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.EditText'.
Error:(6) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Button'.
Error:(3) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material'.
Error:(4) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Body1'.
Error:(5) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Body2'.
Error:(7) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Caption'.
Error:(8) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Display1'.
Error:(9) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Display2'.
Error:(10) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Display3'.
Error:(11) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Display4'.
Error:(12) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Headline'.
Error:(14) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Large'.
Error:(16) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.PopupMenu.Large'.
Error:(18) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.PopupMenu.Small'.
Error:(20) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Medium'.
Error:(22) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Menu'.
Error:(23) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.SearchResult.Subtitle'.
Error:(25) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.SearchResult.Title'.
Error:(27) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Small'.
Error:(29) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Subhead'.
Error:(30) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Title'.
Error:(31) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Subtitle'.
Error:(33) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Subtitle.Inverse'.
Error:(35) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Title'.
Error:(37) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Title.Inverse'.
Error:(39) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionMode.Subtitle'.
Error:(41) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionMode.Title'.
Error:(43) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button'.
Error:(49) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.PopupMenu.Large'.
Error:(51) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.PopupMenu.Small'.
Error:(53) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Button'.
Error:(54) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.TextView.SpinnerItem'.
Error:(55) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Subtitle'.
Error:(57) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Title'.
Error:(161) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ActionBar.TabText'.
Error:(163) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ActionBar.TabView'.
Error:(165) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ActionButton'.
Error:(167) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ActionButton.CloseMode'.
Error:(170) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ActionButton.Overflow'.
Error:(175) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Button'.
Error:(176) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Button.Borderless'.
Error:(177) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Button.Borderless.Colored'.
Error:(180) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Button.Small'.
Error:(181) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ButtonBar'.
Error:(182) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.CompoundButton.CheckBox'.
Error:(183) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.CompoundButton.RadioButton'.
Error:(184) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.DropDownItem.Spinner'.
Error:(188) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ImageButton'.
Error:(189) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Light.ActionBar.TabText'.
Error:(191) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Light.ActionBar.TabText'.
Error:(193) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Light.ActionBar.TabView'.
Error:(195) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Light.PopupMenu'.
Error:(201) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ListPopupWindow'.
Error:(203) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ListView'.
Error:(204) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ListView.DropDown'.
Error:(206) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.PopupMenu'.
Error:(216) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.RatingBar'.
Error:(217) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.SeekBar'.
Error:(218) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Spinner'.
Error:(219) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.TextView.SpinnerItem'.
Error:(220) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Toolbar.Button.Navigation'.
/Users/daniel/AndroidStudioProjects/MyApplication3/app/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.android.support/appcompat-v7/24.0.0-alpha2/res/values-v21/values-v21.xml
Error:(64, 5) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorAccent'.
Error:(64, 5) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorButtonNormal'.
Error:(64, 5) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlActivated'.
Error:(64, 5) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlHighlight'.
Error:(64, 5) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlNormal'.
Error:(64, 5) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorPrimary'.
Error:(64, 5) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorPrimaryDark'.
Error:(108, 5) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:windowElevation'.
Error:(111, 5) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorAccent'.
Error:(111, 5) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorButtonNormal'.
Error:(111, 5) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlActivated'.
Error:(111, 5) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlHighlight'.
Error:(111, 5) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlNormal'.
Error:(111, 5) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorPrimary'.
Error:(111, 5) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorPrimaryDark'.
Error:(155, 5) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:windowElevation'.
Error:(158, 5) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:windowElevation'.
Error:(197, 5) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:overlapAnchor'.
Error:(208, 5) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:overlapAnchor'.
Error:(242, 5) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorAccent'.
Error:(242, 5) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorButtonNormal'.
Error:(242, 5) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlActivated'.
Error:(242, 5) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlHighlight'.
Error:(242, 5) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlNormal'.
Error:(242, 5) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorPrimary'.
Error:(242, 5) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorPrimaryDark'.
/Users/daniel/AndroidStudioProjects/MyApplication3/app/build/intermediates/res/merged/debug/values-v23/values-v23.xml
Error:(37) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Spinner.Underlined'.
Error:(33) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Button.Borderless.Colored'.
Error:(3) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Menu'.
Error:(4) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Inverse'.
Error:(34) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Button.Colored'.
Error:(35) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.RatingBar.Indicator'.
Error:(36) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.RatingBar.Small'.
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/Users/daniel/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools/23.0.3/aapt'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

I even tried to change buildTools version to 17, however it did not help as well (I just again received compile errors but in different places).

Can someone please help me to get it to work? I don't know why it's so complicated to run such usual task and moreover I can't understand why it is not documented in "Getting started" section on developers.android.com.

Also, if possible, I would like to understand why didn't it work from scratch? You can see that the `minSdkVersion` was set up to 16 from the beginning, however it did not work for some reason.

Thanks.

Comment: For the answer to why it wouldn't run with `N` as the target and compiled SDK version with a min SDK of 16 set see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35929636/1435985). You should be able to set your `compiledSdkVersion` and `targetSdkVersion` to 23 and keep the `minSdkVersion` to 16.

Comment: @GeorgeMulligan, thanks for your comment. Well, I tried to set `compiledSdkVersion` to "23.0.3" and `targetSdkVersion` to 23, it fails with the same errors.

Comment: `compiledSdkVersion` should be 23. `buildToolsVersion` is what is set to 23.0.3, at least for the latest version.

Comment: Also, this will not fix your compile errors. You need to make sure the app isn't using features available only in newer SDK versions that are not backwards compatible. `android:paddingStart` and the like were added in API 17 as an example so they will not work in older versions without also specifying the older methods (`android:paddingLeft`, etc).

Comment: Why is it so complex? Isn't it regular task to run application on platform, which is lower than the default one? I unfortunately not that experienced in that, thus I cannot fix it, I just don't know where to check and change those settings...

Comment: Can I somehow create a new project that will be compatible with older API and which will run on my handy?

Comment: Yes. I'm not sure where you got your current project from that it was targeting N to begin with. They try to make it easier by including compatibility libraries that make new features available in older versions. If you create a new project you can select a starting template and set the minsdk version and everything then.

Comment: I did not get project from anywhere, I just created a project with android studio, a project with empty activity does not work, despite I set the minimum api version to 16 during the project creation.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109325/discussion-between-george-mulligan-and-sciencese).