# In Android Studio I'm getting IllegalStateException: Android platform not set for module:

Tags: android, build.gradle, android-studio-2.0

I am trying to run an Android app on my Mac that was created on another Mac.

I'm not sure what is causing this problem exactly but here is some information if you could try to help identify what I need to fix.

This is the first error that appears:
    IllegalStateException: Android platform not set for module:

And a minute later I get this:

```
RuntimeException: Unable to locate Android SDK used by project:
```

Here I'm referencing API version 24:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="net.learn2develop.Layouts"
    android:versionCode="440"
    android:versionName="440" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="24" />
```

which is located here:
[image]

and referenced here as well:

This may help as well:

```
Android platform not set for module: 
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Android platform not set for module: 
    at com.android.tools.idea.run.editor.DevicePicker.createChecker(DevicePicker.java:158)
    at com.android.tools.idea.run.editor.DevicePicker.<init>(DevicePicker.java:106)
    at com.android.tools.idea.run.editor.DeployTargetPickerDialog.<init>(DeployTargetPickerDialog.java:102)
    at com.android.tools.idea.run.editor.ShowChooserTargetProvider.showPrompt(ShowChooserTargetProvider.java:97)
    at com.android.tools.idea.run.AndroidRunConfigurationBase.getDeployTarget(AndroidRunConfigurationBase.java:659)
    at com.android.tools.idea.run.AndroidRunConfigurationBase.getState(AndroidRunConfigurationBase.java:360)
    at com.intellij.execution.runners.ExecutionEnvironment.getState(ExecutionEnvironment.java:158)
    at com.intellij.execution.runners.BaseProgramRunner.execute(BaseProgramRunner.java:55)
    at com.intellij.execution.runners.GenericProgramRunner.execute(GenericProgramRunner.java:31)
    at com.intellij.execution.runners.BaseProgramRunner.execute(BaseProgramRunner.java:50)
    at com.intellij.execution.runners.GenericProgramRunner.execute(GenericProgramRunner.java:31)
    at com.intellij.execution.ProgramRunnerUtil.executeConfiguration(ProgramRunnerUtil.java:94)
    at com.intellij.execution.impl.ExecutionManagerImpl.start(ExecutionManagerImpl.java:114)
    at com.intellij.execution.impl.ExecutionManagerImpl.access$400(ExecutionManagerImpl.java:65)
    at com.intellij.execution.impl.ExecutionManagerImpl$7.run(ExecutionManagerImpl.java:503)
    at com.intellij.util.concurrency.QueueProcessor.runSafely(QueueProcessor.java:238)
    at com.intellij.util.Alarm$Request$1.run(Alarm.java:352)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.LaterInvocator$FlushQueue.runNextEvent(LaterInvocator.java:337)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.LaterInvocator$FlushQueue.run(LaterInvocator.java:321)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:209)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:715)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(EventQueue.java:82)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:676)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:674)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:86)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:685)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:866)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:654)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:381)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:296)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:211)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:196)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:188)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:122)
```

Please let me know if there is something else I can show. I got repeated errors when I tried to upload my run configuration.

Thank you for your help

Comment: Make sure your `compileSdkVersion` `buildToolsVersion` code should be valid in your `build.gradle`. See [CommonsWare](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35929636/2949612) answer here.

Answer (score 0):

On this current mac machine the path of your android sdk is not defined or not available. You have to give your android studio the path of of sdk folder on your mac machine. You might get some help from this link.
[Android Studio - How to Change Android SDK Path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16581752/android-studio-how-to-change-android-sdk-path)