# Disable Manifest Merger in Android Gradle Build 3.1.2

Tags: android, gradle, android-build

```
   android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    androidManifestFile variant.outputs[0].processResources.manifestFile = file('src/main/AndroidManifest.xml')
    variant.processManifest.enabled=false
   }
```

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.

  > Cannot set the value of read-only property 'manifestFile' for task ':app:processDebugResources' of type com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.LinkApplicationAndroidResourcesTask.

Answer (score 0):

Use `manifestOutputFile` instead of `manifestFile` as follows:

```
android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    androidManifestFile variant.outputs[0].processResources.manifestOutputFile = file('src/main/AndroidManifest.xml')
    variant.processManifest.enabled=false
   }
```

Also remember to disable `Instant Run` option in case you are still facing issues, since it has some issues. In case its mandatory for you to use `Instant Run` refer to this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36874191/editing-androidmanifest-xml-in-gradle-task-processmanifest-dolast-has-no-effect) which describes how to achieve it